have worked vs worked
I have worked in this hospital.
I worked in this hospital.
Hello. Are these sentences grammatically correct? Do I need to add words at the end? ( for example for 5 years ) I know what perfect tense is, but I always get confused.
Past tense is something that happened in the past.
Perfect tense is an event that started in the past, is still going on or has ended within a short time. But like I said, "ended ''
After all, they're both over in one way or another.
If I say these two sentences to the other person, can he or she understand whether I still work in that hospital or not? Is there anything grammatically I should add to this sentence?
I would be very grateful if you could enlighten me on this issue.
Best regards.

They are acceptable as they are, but you need to add something to the first one if you want to express that you still work there.

Even if we say i have worked in this hospital for 5 years,Isn't it also understood like this : yes i have worked here for 5 years but i left 2 days ago ?

No. If you have left the job, you would say I worked here (or I used to work here).

You should use the present perfect "have worked" only in a context where that work period is relevant to some other fact in the present. In other words, while "I have worked in a hospital" is grammatically correct, you would never use this sentence in isolation. It would always be used in a longer discussion where it is logically connected to something in the present.

Does this answer your question? Present Perfect vs Simple Past

"I worked in the hospital for five years" implies that I don't work there anymore. "I have worked in the hospital for five years" means that I started work there five years ago (2019) and still work there.

But isn't the perfect tense also understood like this: I worked for 5 years in this hospital, but I left recently, no matter when.

@emilywenly Yes and No, present perfect is speaking about an action that happened in past like simple past. But sometimes the action is still ongoing and sometimes not. When the action is not ongoing, present perfect is just for showing the relation between past action and present time. Like an effect of something that is the result of the past action in present. Simple past is just about past. Present perfect is about past and present as I described at the beginning

The sentence "I have worked in this hospital" means that the person has previously worked in the hospital, but it does not necessarily mean or emphasize that they are still working there.
You should use "I work here (in hospital)" if you want to speak only about your employment there. Or you can say "I have worked in the hospital for X years" to talk about the time you have started working there.
Most learners' problem is that they are studying only grammar but not semantics. Grammar is elaborating how sentences are formed. It's not going to teach you what a sentence can mean exactly.
Perhaps native speakers are somewhat harsh to learners (by downvoting ) because they don't know learners doesn't have a good education system or leader and this kind of questions are quite common.
I'm a learner too and will be glad to hear anything useful about this topic and my grammatical problems as well.
